# How to simulate rectangular surface code with stim?

Tags: error-correction, surface-code, stim

The [Stim package](https://github.com/quantumlib/stim) is a tool for simulation and analysis of quantum stabilizer circuits. Stim's built-in surface code circuit generation, [stim.Circuit.generated](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/wiki/Stim-v1.6-Python-API-Reference#stim.Circuit.generated), can run different code tasks (rotated and unrotated surface codes for X and Z error probabilities for example) and takes as parameter the "desired code distance of the generated circuit".
Is it possible to give two distances $d_X$ and $d_Z$ for rectangular surface codes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `stim.Circuit.generated` method doesn't support rectangular surface codes (this method is only meant to generate some common example circuits to get going, rather than all possible variants of surface code circuits). However, I also wanted to make some small tweaks to these example circuits recently, so I translated the surface code circuits from C++ to Python so that I could change them without needing to use the Stim C++ API. I've open sourced the code, so feel free to use it and make the necessary tweaks for generating rectangular surface codes: https://github.com/oscarhiggott/StimCircuits

Comment: The PR has been merged on Apr 13, 2023 so I'll accept this answer ! Thanks again Oscar !